# Is Palindrome? using invariant programming

Tags: python, tail-recursion, palindrome, invariants

The following code doesn't work.

```
def isPal(s):
    def checkPal(s, acc):
        if len(s) <= 1:
            return acc
        else:
            return checkPal(s[1:-1] (acc and (s[0] == s[-1])))
    return checkPal(s, True)
```

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Could you tell me please, what's wrong with it? I cannot find the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
return checkPal(s[1:-1] (acc and (s[0] == s[-1])))
```

`s[1:-1]` is a string and it is followed by `(...)` which is interpreted as a function call.

Probably, you want add a comma and change it to:

```
return checkPal(s[1:-1], (acc and (s[0] == s[-1])))
```

You can also skip brackets:

```
return checkPal(s[1:-1], acc and (s[0] == s[-1]))
```

Comment: Haha, that's what happens when you work with several languages parallel - messed up Python with OZ. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in the second `checkPal` `return` statement. Here's the fixed version:

```
checkPal(s[1:-1], (acc and (s[0] == s[-1])))
```

Without the comma, you are trying to invoke the string `s[1:-1]` as a function which is causing your error.